# I am making a warn function on my discord.py bot and I don't know why it is giving me an attribute error

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def warn(self,ctx,member = discord.Member,*,reason = None):

    await member.send("You were warned in {} for: {}".format(member.guild,reason))

    embed = discord.Embed(":poop:***{} has been warned".format(member))

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yomamahahaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/yomamahahaha/Desktop/poopshitter/bot.py", line 96, in warn
    await member.send("You were warned in {} for: {}".format(member.guild,reason))
  File "C:\Users\yomamahahaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 864, in send
    channel = await self._get_channel()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_get_channel'
```

I don't have get_channel in this code so I was wondering what the problem would be.

Comment: It will be easier to help us, when you provide full exception output. It looks like somewhere to function wrong object type is passed.

Comment: I added the full exception traceback. I hope it helps bc I'm pretty stumped :\.

Comment: do you have `intents.members` enabled?

Comment: await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed) why do you need the channel here since you are not pulling it through ID, Just use the ctx.send for normal messages.

Comment: I have intents.members enabled and I fixed the ctx.send thing but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed 2 things.

1. You want to use `:` instead of `=` in line 3. If you use `:` discord.py will try to search for a user with that ID, Mention, etc.. `=` is used to pass optional arguments. That means you do not have to specify the reason when you run that command.
2. The `discord.Embed()` function will not work like you've shown it here. The correct way to call this function is `embed = discord.Embed(description= f":poop:***{member} has been warned")`. That way discord.py knows how the embed should look like. Embeds have quite a few customizable things. Examples: Title, description, color, images and multiple fields.

Here is the command with my suggestions. If you have any questions about it, let me know.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = "No reason provided"):
     await member.send(f"You were warned in {member.guild}. Reason: {reason}")
     embed = discord.Embed(description=f":poop:***{member} has been warned.")
     await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```